# Why doesn't my tank move when I press "a" and "d"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, user-controls

Currently, I am stuck on trying to get my tank to move when the user presses "a" and "d". The lines involving pressing a key to move the tank seem correct and I believe should work. This is also my first time using one of these forums. Please provide feedback so I can improve. Thank you for your help.

I have asked my teacher and friends for help, but they are all wondering why the tank will not move. I also have searched over the internet and youtube for answers. A weird thing is that my friend and I directly copied a youtube video on user movement where the user can move a rectangle around. My friend can hold down "w","a","s",or "d" to move the rectangle, but I can not hold down "w","a","s",or "d" to move it but need to spam the button. What is weird is that when you move your mouse around, I can then hold down "w","a","s",or "d".

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import math
import random

width = 640 
height = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("2 Player Tanks")


def gameloop(): 
    pygame.init()
    time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    screen.fill(white)

    tankx = 100
    tanky = 100
    tankwidth = 40
    tankheight = 20
    turretwidth = 5 
    wheelwidth = 5
    tankmove = 5

    def tank(x,y):
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,black,(x,y),10)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,(x-tankheight,y,tankwidth,tankheight))
        pygame.draw.line(screen,black,(x,y),(x-20,y-20), turretwidth)

        startx = 15
        for i in range(7):
            pygame.draw.circle(screen,black,(x-startx,y+20),wheelwidth)
            startx -= 5

   for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           pygame.quit()

        keys= pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            tankx -= tankmove
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            tankx += tankmove
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            tanky -= tankmove
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            tanky += tankmove         

         tank(tankx,tanky)
         pygame.display.update()

gameloop()
```

I want the player to be able to use "a" and "d" to move the tank horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

The event loop is executed only when an event occurs. This means it is executed when a key is pressed or a key is released — however, when a key is held down, no event occurs and the event loop is not executed.

You've got to evaluate the key presses in the main loop (in scope of `gameloop`) rather than in the event loop:

e.g.

```py
def gameloop(): 

    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    # <--
    keys= pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        tankx -= tankmove
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        tankx += tankmove
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        tanky -= tankmove
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        tanky += tankmove         

    tank(tankx,tanky)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Note: [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns the current states of the keys and the states are evaluated and updated when [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) is called.

---

The position of the tank is reset at the begin of the frame, because the variables  `tankx` and `tanky` are set at the begin of `gameloop`:

> ```
>  def gameloop(): 
>       #[...]
>
>       tankx = 100
>       tanky = 100
> ```

Define the variables in global scope, and use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) to access them.
Decrease the speed of the tank, because it would move very rapidly (`tankmove = 1`).

The  [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) should be called once only, at the begin of application.

e.g.

```py
def gameloop(): 
    global tankx, tanky, tankmove

    tankwidth = 40
    tankheight = 20
    turretwidth = 5 
    wheelwidth = 5

    time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    screen.fill(white)

    # [...]

pygame.init()

tankx = 100
tanky = 100
tankmove = 1
run = True
while run:
    gameloop()
```

---

> I can move the tank with a randomized background, but the program keeps on drawing a new tank. To fix this, I added a screen.fill(white). That fixes the drawing problem, but now I have no background.

Don't draw the *random* background to the window. Create a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) and draw the *random* background to the surface.
[`.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the background surface to the screen in every frame:

```py
background_surface = pygame.Surface((widht, height))
# draw background to "background_surface" rather then "screen"
# [...]
```

```py
def gameloop():

    # [...]

    # blit background instead of screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(background_surface, (0, 0))

    # [...]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand what you are saying and have outdented the part mentioned above, but the tank is still unmovable. Is there a way to rephrase/rewrite keys= pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        tankx -= tankmove
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        tankx += tankmove
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        tanky -= tankmove
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        tanky += tankmove

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I solved the moving part, but I have a part of my program that randomizes the background. This part is also in the gameloop so it keeps on repeating itself. Eventually, I would like to add a play again feature to my game. Do I need to make another function where game loop is inside?

Comment: @AT42 Create a function, which initializes all states of the program (like `tankx`, `tanky`, ...) everything what has to be set initially before the game is started. Call this function once, when the game has to be restarted. The game loop can run on. Remember, the function has to use the `global` statement.

Comment: I did what you told me. I can move the tank with a randomized background, but the program keeps on drawing a new tank. To fix this, I added a screen.fill(white). That fixes the drawing problem, but now I have no background.

Comment: @AT42 Use a background surface. See the extension to the answer (last part).

Comment: I did that, but I'm getting the message local variable 'tankx' referenced before assignment. I've already said global tankx. I feel like my organization is off and its just confusing me.

Comment: I know I shouldn't do this, but can I just "answer my question" and post my code so you can organize it?